Solve the problem of STM32H750 SPI1 replying error as a slave
Problems encountered : The STM32H750 (slave) can correctly receive the message from the host, but I don't know why the reply to the host is incorrect. Please help me, thank you!!!
Connection method : Other MCU (master) <--SPI1--> STM32H750 (slave)
Error code:  STM32H750 receives data via HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(). The content received by buf2 is correct. buf1 should be [1, 100], but the host receives 100 0x02 (confirmed by logic analyzer). This function returns HAL_TIMEOUT. Through debugging, it is found that __HAL_SPI_GET_FLAG(hspi, SPI_FLAG_TXP) is always 0, which may not be written to the transmit register at all.
for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
       buf1[i] = i + 1;
}

HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, buf1, buf2, 100, 1000);

while ((initial_TxXferCount > 0UL) || (initial_RxXferCount > 0UL))
    {
      /* Check the TXP flag */
      if ((__HAL_SPI_GET_FLAG(hspi, SPI_FLAG_TXP)) && (initial_TxXferCount > 0UL))
      {
        *((__IO uint8_t *)&hspi->Instance->TXDR) = *((const uint8_t *)hspi->pTxBuffPtr);
        hspi->pTxBuffPtr += sizeof(uint8_t);
        hspi->TxXferCount--;
        initial_TxXferCount = hspi->TxXferCount;
      }

      /* Check the RXP flag */
      if ((__HAL_SPI_GET_FLAG(hspi, SPI_FLAG_RXP)) && (initial_RxXferCount > 0UL))
      {
        *((uint8_t *)hspi->pRxBuffPtr) = *((__IO uint8_t *)&hspi->Instance->RXDR);
        hspi->pRxBuffPtr += sizeof(uint8_t);
        hspi->RxXferCount--;
        initial_RxXferCount = hspi->RxXferCount;
      }

      /* Timeout management */
      if ((((HAL_GetTick() - tickstart) >=  Timeout) && (Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)) || (Timeout == 0U))
      {
        /* Call standard close procedure with error check */
        SPI_CloseTransfer(hspi);

        /* Unlock the process */
        __HAL_UNLOCK(hspi);

        SET_BIT(hspi->ErrorCode, HAL_SPI_ERROR_TIMEOUT);
        hspi->State = HAL_SPI_STATE_READY;
        return HAL_TIMEOUT;
      }
    }

Initialization code:
void MX_SPI1_Slave_Init(void)
{
hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_HARD_INPUT;
hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 0x0;
hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.NSSPolarity = SPI_NSS_POLARITY_LOW;
hspi1.Init.FifoThreshold = SPI_FIFO_THRESHOLD_01DATA;
hspi1.Init.TxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
hspi1.Init.RxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
hspi1.Init.MasterSSIdleness = SPI_MASTER_SS_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
hspi1.Init.MasterInterDataIdleness = SPI_MASTER_INTERDATA_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
hspi1.Init.MasterReceiverAutoSusp = SPI_MASTER_RX_AUTOSUSP_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.MasterKeepIOState = SPI_MASTER_KEEP_IO_STATE_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.IOSwap = SPI_IO_SWAP_DISABLE;
if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
}

The STM32H750 can send and receive data correctly as a host, but the data received as a slave is not correctly returned to the host.

I don't know the ST bloatware "HAL" but a function named HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive does not make sense on a SPI slave - that's a conceptually strange function. SPI is full duplex and the master is always the one initiating the transmission. Meaning that the slave will have to prepare the data to be sent in advance, by placing it in the tx buffer. If that's what the function does, then it's still wrong since that would mean that you'd be stuck busy waiting for whenever transmission occurs before you can receive.

The main problem is that the full flag of TX Fifo is always 1, which makes it impossible to write new data, but I didn't write it and it should be empty. And I can receive the correct data

So it should probably be cleared along with initialization? When writing SPI drivers yourself, these flags are often cleared in peculiar ways, such as reading the status register followed by an immediate read of the data register. How/if ST did that or if this particular MCU requires that, I wouldn't know. Also, there's a common problem with some debuggers that read the memory map, causing reads to such flags and thereby destroying them. If that's the problem you'll notice that the program works when free running but not when single-stepping.
